# Microsoft Excel autofill column with the series R10, R20, R30

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to autofill column with the series R10, R20, R30, but not able to.

I have tried to right click and drag and select series but was not able to.

Comment: You have to select R10, R20 and put the mouse at the right bottom corner  of the cell where R20 is and when you see + pointer left click and drag, if it is repeating click on the small square(paste options) and choose fill series

Answer (score 2):

Select cells with your values ("R10", "R20", "R30"), left-click lower-right corner of the selection and drag it down. Works in Excel 2010.

Comment: There's a very small square icon in the lower-right corner of the selected cells. Left-clicking on this and dragging it will expand the selection and auto-fill the next values in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any cell and enter:

```
="R" & ROWS($1:1)*10
```

and copy downwards:

[image]